# List of file names (blobs) stored in google cloud storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

There is a GCS bucket in my GCP project which has millions of files and someone else regularly uploads files there every day.

It is too slow to search for a specific filename to see whether it is uploaded because of the huge number of files there.

Is there any way to list file names and upload dates in a BQ table or CSV file or whatever? It needs to be updated with any new file upload so I assume the Google Cloud function would be a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could definitely [subscribe to Google Cloud Storage events](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) from within your function - we have an [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-dotnet/tree/main/examples/Google.Cloud.Functions.Examples.StorageImageAnnotator) which does just that, so that each time an object with an image content type is uploaded, another API is used to create annotations. (The deployment instructions are in [the example documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-dotnet/blob/main/docs/examples.md#storageimageannotator).)

So you could listen for finalized/deleted/archived events and modify the database directly - and then potentially *also* have a periodic task (e.g. once per day) that lists all the objects and updates the database in bulk, just as a way of rectifying any errors that might occur. The periodic task could be via a [Pub/Sub subscription using Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub) for example.

The Cloud Function could then easily write to Cloud Spanner, BigQuery etc. It's worth considering implications of concurrency, of course - you'll want to be able to handle multiple concurrent function invocations if a lot of files are added or removed at the same time. (That would make keeping a CSV file somewhat trickier than using an actual database.)

I don't *know* of any functionality built into Google Cloud to just say "Please make the list of GCS objects from this bucket available via BigQuery" - it's possible that it exists, of course.

Comment: > I don't know of any functionality built into Google Cloud to just say "Please make the list of GCS objects from this bucket available via BigQuery" - it's possible that it exists, of course.
>

<br>The closest would be to create an inventory report and then import the report into BigQuery:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/insights/inventory-reports

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly for this king of use case I wrote [that article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/extend-cloud-storage-filtering-with-bigquery-object-table-7ce4a0f75a3d) which use object tables in BigQuery.

If you have millions of object, I recommend to [use cache](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/object-table-introduction#metadata_caching_for_performance) to speed up the search (but your data won't be always up to date).